# Replace dataframe missing values with linear trend

Tags: r

I've an imported dataframe where some values are missing in `x2`. Here a simplified example.

I'd like to replace the missing values with a linear trend between the last and next available.

Any suggestion on how to do it?

```
a <- data.frame(x1=1:11, x2=c(6,"","","","",12,"","",4,"",20))
a

   x1 x2
1   1  6
2   2   
3   3   
4   4   
5   5   
6   6 12
7   7   
8   8   
9   9  4
10 10   
11 11 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `approx` like below

```
transform(
  a,
  x2 = approx(x1[nzchar(x2)], na.omit(as.numeric(x2)), x1)$y
)
```

which gives

```
   x1        x2
1   1  6.000000
2   2  7.200000
3   3  8.400000
4   4  9.600000
5   5 10.800000
6   6 12.000000
7   7  9.333333
8   8  6.666667
9   9  4.000000
10 10 12.000000
11 11 20.000000
```

Comment: Works fine!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what's the meaning of $y ?

Comment: @Andrew `approx` returns a list, include `$x` and `$y`, and you need `$y` only here. You can use `?approx` and read the manual.